# QueryBuilder and inner join

Tags: sql, symfony, doctrine-orm

Here is the request :

```
select concat(user.nom, ' ', user.prenom), trace.action
from MyBundle:Ttrace trace
innerjoin MyBundle:User user on user.id = trace.user
where trace.datfin is null
```

Can somebody translate that using queryBuilder ?

Thank you
I tried this but it does not work :

```
 $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder()
            ->select("trace.action")
            ->addSelect("concat(user.nom, ' ', user.prenom)")
            ->from('MyBundle:Ttrace', 'trace')
            ->innerjoin('trace', 'MyBundle:User', 'user', 'user.id = trace.user')
            ->where('trace.datfin is null');
```

But it does not work.

I also tried :

```
$this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder()
            ->select("trace.action")
            ->addSelect("concat(user.nom, ' ', user.prenom)")
            ->from('MyBundle:Ttrace', 'trace')
            ->join('MyBundle:User', 'user')
            ->where('trace.datfin is null');
```

but sql query is wrong with:
     innerjoin user on (trace.datfin is null)  NONSENSE!! and of course no where in the sql query

So, does somebody know (it is easy they say) how to build it (with a query builder)

ty

Comment: Try to search and doing by yourself, and then we can help if you are stuck

Comment: it's easy if you read: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html#querying-for-objects-using-doctrine-s-query-builder and http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#dql-select-examples

Comment: the documentation you proposed is not acurate for the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hoping it is gonna help somebody :

```
$qb = $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder()
  ->select('trace.action')
  ->addSelect("concat(user.nom, ' ', user.prenom)")
  ->from('MyBundle:Ttrace', 'trace');
$qb->join('MyBundle:User', 'u', Join::WITH, $qb->expr()->eq('trace.user', 'u.id'));
$qb->where($qb->expr()->isNull('trace.datfin');
```